# video_view cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java.How to fix this issue

Tags: android

video_view cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /mp4player/src/com/project/mp4player

[image]

when I try edit manually

like    "   public static int video_view;"

in the R.java

It always again and again  reverts to the original  i.e

**R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!**

How to fixc this type of issues.

Comment: Try to rename this id and clean and build again.

Answer (score 0):

You should never edit R.java manually it is automatically generated by looking at your xml files.

What you should do is have a VideoView in you activity_main.xml with `android:id="@+id/video_view` and then it will generate it in the R file.

Comment: Thank you for that valuable answers.

Comment: Thanks Now my problem got fixed

Answer (score 0):

check your R import,
it should be the R.java from your package, not android.R
and yes, you must have a view with id video_view on your layout xml file